# Redirecting System.out and appending to an existing file

Tags: java, file, logging, io-redirection

I have a Java program which runs every 10 minutes. I want to capture a log of this process, for example consider (what essentially my program does):

```
public static void someFunction()
{
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(LOG_DIR));
    System.out.append("whatever I am appending about my program")
}
```

In this case `someFunction` will be called from `main` every 10 minutes. However, it always overwrites the file specified by `LOG_DIR`. I think this is because it just creates a new file and saves over what was previously in file `LOG_DIR`. Thus my attempt to append to the end of the file is superfluous.

1. How can my program write to the end of some file when the function is called every 10 minutes?

Comment: Use a logging framework. Or use a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)).

Answer (score 4):

The best solution would be to leverage one of several existing logging frameworks. However, if you insist on rolling your own, you need to append to your output file, as opposed to overwriting it:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(LOG_DIR, true)));
```

Note that boolean argument to `FileOutputStream`, this specifies that the stream should be opened in ***append*** mode.